# Infinitives used as an adjective modifier

Tags: infinitives

It is easy to beat him.

Here, 'It' is used as a Subject placeholder.

To beat him is easy.

My question is in 'It is easy to beat him'....the Infinitive clause ' to beat him' is modifying and describing(giving more information) the predicative Adjective 'easy' ?

Like in this sentence,

He was ready **to go to the movies**.

Or, it is just an extraposed subject not modifying anything in the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *It is easy to beat him.*
>
> [2] *To beat him is easy.*

The infinitival clause in [1] doesn't modify anything.

In Extraposition the "it" is a dummy element  serving the syntactic purpose of filling the subject position; the extraposed element doesn’t give the meaning (reference) of it but serves simply as a semantic argument of the VP.

Note that the subordinate clause is not part of the PC. The PC is just "easy", just as it is in the non-extraposed [2].

> *He was ready to go to the movies.*

Here, the subordinate clause is complement of "ready", the element that lexically licenses it.

Note that you can say "He is one of those ready to go the movies".

Comment: I searched the topic argument, it is an expression that helps complete the meaning of a predicate. But I think this definition is on the basis of Syntactic argument. But What is semantic argument?